# setbounds on google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, bounds, fitbounds, setbounds

I'm trying to set the bounds of a map 
fitbounds doesnt work because it puts some space around the bounds therefore doing

```
{{{map.fitBounds(map.getBounds())}}}
```

a few times will quickly zoom the map out

I need to be able to do

```
{{{map.setBounds(map.getBounds())}}}
```

and for nothing to happen

#### please note I am using v3 of the api and therefore do not have access to getBoundsZoomLevel

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, I'm assuming you want all your points to be visible on the map with the highest possible zoom level. I accomplished this by initializing the zoom level of the map to 16(not sure if it's the highest possible zoom level on V3).

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), { zoom: 16
                                        , center: marker_point
                                        , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Then after that I did the bounds stuff:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

//you can have a loop here of all you marker points
//begin loop
bounds.extend(marker_point);
//end loop

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Result: Success!

Answer (score 0):

`FitBounds` like you say extends the bounds to exceed those of the second map, to make the bounds be exactly the same, you can set the center and the zoom.

```
map2.setCenter(map.getCenter());
map2.setZoom(map.getZoom());
```

As in this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/KmNaX/

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guyzz when nothing was working for me i planned to take this approach .. and it worked for me.. I took the coordinates from view port and then mapped the same to bounds.. this approach works ..

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    if(address == null || address== "") {
        alert('Address field is Empty.. !');
    } else {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address' : address
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // If geocoder status is OK then locate the geometry,..
                var location = results[0].geometry.location
                // Obtaining the lat lang of new position on map.. 
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(),location.lng());

                map.setCenter(location);

                // view port gives us the map bounds for a particular location.. 
                **var viewportloc = String(results[0].geometry.viewport);
                var res = viewportloc.replace('((','').replace('))','').replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',');

                //alert(res[0]+" - "+res[1]+" - "+res[2]+" - "+res[3]);
                var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(res[0],res[1]);
                var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(res[2],res[3]);

                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                bounds.extend(sw);
                bounds.extend(ne);

                map.fitBounds(bounds);**

                addMarker(location);
                setonMap(map);

            } else {
                document.getElementById('address').value = "";
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```